# Regex global match term until delimiter, result without term/delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex, match

My string contains (FUDI) messages delimited by `;\n`. I try to extract all messages beginning with a certain string.

The following regex finds the correct messages, but still include the delimiter and the search term.

```js
var input = 'a b;\n'
    + 'a b c;\n'
    + 'b;\n'
    + 'b c;\n'
    + 'b c d;\n';

function search(input, term){
    var regex = new RegExp('(^|;\n)' + term + '([^;\n]?)+', 'g');
    return input.match(regex);
}

console.log(search(input, 'a b'));
// current: ["a b", ";↵a b c"]
// wanted1: ["a b", "a b c"]
// wanted2: ["", "c"]

console.log(search(input, 'b'));
// current: [";↵b", ";↵b c", ";↵b c d"]
// wanted1: ["b", "b c", "b c d"]
// wanted2: ["", "c", "c d"]
```

1. How can the delimiter be removed (wanted1)?
2. Is it possible to only return everything after the search term (wanted2)?

I am a regex beginner so any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: solves wanted1 using /gm**

```js
var input = 'a b;\n'
    + 'a b c;\n'
    + 'b;\n'
    + 'b c;\n'
    + 'b c d;\n';

function search(input, term){
    var regex = new RegExp('^' + term + '([^;]*)', 'gm');
    return input.match(regex);
}

console.log(search(input, 'a b'));
// current: ["a b", "a b c"]
// wanted2: ["", "c"]

console.log(search(input, 'b'));
// current: ["b", "b c", "b c d"]
// wanted2: ["", "c", "c d"]
```

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of the delimiter, you should use `.split()` instead of `.match()`.

```
str.split(/;\n/);
```

Using your example:

```
('a b;\n'
+ 'a b c;\n'
+ 'b;\n'
+ 'b c;\n'
+ 'b c d;\n').split(/;\n/)
// ["a b", "a b c", "b", "b c", "b c d", ""]
```

Then, to find the match, you have to iterate through the split result and do the string matching:

```
function search(input, term)
{
    var inputs = input.split(/;\n/),
    res = [], pos;

    for (var i = 0, item; item = inputs[i]; ++i) {
        pos = item.indexOf(term);
        if (pos != -1) {
            // term matches the input, add the remainder to the result.
            res.push(item.substring(pos + term.length));
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jack! I hoped to not use a loop. But at least with a loop it is more readable.